# twitter bootstrap popovers not working inside modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Even when in the bootstrap docs popovers inside modals works, I can not manage to make it work in my own code.

If you open the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFSkg/) you can notice that popovers and tooltips are not working inside the modal. I believe a I've replicated the sample code correctly.

I ran the fiddle in incognito mode to rule out chrome extensions issues with no luck.

I guess I'm missing something here. Can you spot what I have done wrong?

See the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Heading</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
          <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>
          <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
          <p>This <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-default popover-test" title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">button</a> should trigger a popover on click.</p>
          <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
          <p><a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip">This link</a> and <a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip">that link</a> should have tooltips on hover.</p>
          <hr>
          <h4>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior</h4>
          <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
          <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
          <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
          <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
          <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
          <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
<div class="bs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>      
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the tooltip, popover are *Opt-in* functionality, which means you have to manually initialize the plugin to get it work

In this case, you have to place this in your script file

```
$('.tooltip-test').tooltip();
$('.popover-test').popover();
```

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFSkg/3/)

Comment: Now the tooltips are working! Thanks any idea about the popover?